# php mail with bcc not working

Tags: php, email, bcc

I am using below code for sending mail with cc and bcc.

```
$headers="From: $name <{$fromAddress}>\r\n".
            "Reply-To: info@test.com\r\n".
            "Cc: abc@gmail.com\r\n".
            "BCC: pqr@gmail.com\r\n".
            "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
            "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";

@mail($toAddres,$subject,$message,$headers,$parameters);
```

All the things are working fine including reply-to, cc but the bcc is not working.

In the mailbox headers, it is not showing me the bcc mail address. What do I need to fix it?

Comment: Did you try `Bcc`

Comment: bcc are hidden copy carbon. If you don't see them it's normal.

Comment: Do you mean that the Bcc recipient does not get the email? **bcc not working** Is not a helpful description

Comment: The `B` stands for blind. It means that none of the other recipients will see the address. Does `pqr@gmail.com` actually receive the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with **ICC** (**I**nvisible **C**arbon **C**opy) wish is the second name of **BCC**.

By the way, **BCC** is **B**lind **C**arbon **C**opy. So if you don't see them in your mail it's normal.

Comment: Blind Carbon Copy

Comment: @JeremyM. thanks .... i am unbale to see bcc mail id in mail header but mail id in bcc getting mail

Answer (score 0):

without having a close look to your code I think the problem is that they do not recieve your e-mail which is set as BCC

the reason might be you used `BCC` instead of `Bcc`

Corrected $header

```
$headers="From: $name <{$fromAddress}>\r\n".
        "Reply-To: info@test.com\r\n".
        "Cc: abc@gmail.com\r\n".
        "Bcc: pqr@gmail.com\r\n".
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

I have changed the BCC:  to Bcc: